# Exact Solution of Ising Model in Open Boundary condition

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model

What will be the exact expression of the partition function for 1d Ising model, if we consider open boundary case (This implies that the last spin in the sequence does not interact with the first spin)? 
If I go by the Transfer Matrix method what will be the problems?